# No adapter attached when I attached the adapter

Tags: kotlin

I'm working on a simple APP in Kotlin that calls an API of Pokemons and show them on the screen, but I started to get an error that says there is no adapter attached even when I attached an adapter.

Here's the error: `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`

And here's the code:

This is the MainActivity.kt where I attached the adapter:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView


    var loaded = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvPokemons)

        if(!loaded){
            Thread(Runnable {
                loadPokemons()
            }).start()

            loaded = true
        }
    }



    private fun loadPokemons() {
        val pokemonsApiResult = PokemonRepository.listPokemons()



        pokemonsApiResult?.results?.let {
            val pokemons: List<Pokemon?> = it.map { pokemonResult ->
                val number = pokemonResult.url
                    .replace("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/", "")
                    .replace("/", "").toInt()
                val pokemonApiResult = PokemonRepository.getPokemon(number)


                pokemonApiResult?.let{
                    Pokemon(
                        pokemonApiResult.id,
                        pokemonApiResult.name,
                        pokemonApiResult.types.map {type ->
                            type.type

                        }
                    )

                }
            }

            val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

            recyclerView.post {
                recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
                recyclerView.adapter = PokemonAdapter(pokemons)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code of the adapter called PokemonAdapter.kt

```
class PokemonAdapter(
    private val items: List<Pokemon?>,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PokemonAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.pokemon_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        holder.bindView(item)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val ivPokemon: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPokemon)
        private val tvNumber: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNumber)
        private val tvName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName)
        private val tvType1: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvType1)
        private val tvType2: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvType2)

        fun bindView(item: Pokemon?) {
            item?.let {
                Glide.with(itemView.context).load(it.imageUrl).into(ivPokemon)
                tvNumber.text = "Nº ${item.formattedNumber}"
                tvName.text = item.formattedName
                tvType1.text = item.types[0].name.capitalize()

                if (item.types.size > 1) {
                    tvType2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    tvType2.text = item.types[1].name.capitalize()
                } else {
                    tvType2.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```